# Finding the indexes of values from a list to a different list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Using Python 3, I want to iterate over the items in a first list in ascending order, and find the item's index in a second list to store it into a third result list.

Below is a working example:

```
list1 = [53, 65, 67, 37, 14, 98, 122, 124, 183]
list2 = [0, 14, 37, 53, 65, 67, 98, 122, 124, 183, 199]

wanted_output = getWantedOutput(list1, list2)

print(wanted_output)

>>> [3, 4, 5, 2, 1, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most efficient solution for long lists is to preprocess the second list and convert it into a dictionary where list items are keys and their positions are values. Then look up the elements from the first list in that dictionary:

```
positions = {item: pos for pos, item in enumerate(list2)}
[positions[item] for item in list1]
#[3, 4, 5, 2, 1, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Answer (score 3):

This approach is less readable than the other given answer, but it is faster if your list is long.

```
wanted_output = []
for item in list1:
    try:
        wanted_output.append(list2.index(item))
    except ValueError: # item not in list2
        continue
```

Answer (score 2):

```
list1 = [53, 65, 67, 37, 14, 98, 122, 124, 183]
list2 = [0, 14, 37, 53, 65, 67, 98, 122, 124, 183, 199]

[list2.index(x) for x in list1 if x in list2]

Output:
[3, 4, 5, 2, 1, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Comment: You can make the solution much faster if you create an auxiliary `set(list2)` and check the membership in the set rather than on the list.

Comment: This incurs a further memory and time cost, which is likely only amortized if the `list2` is very large.

Comment: @zr0gravity7 It takes no extra time because building a set is an O(N) operation and set lookup is an O(1) operation, but a list lookup is an O(N) operation.

Comment: "set lookup is an O(1) operation" was not aware of that. Good to know. This and the accepted answer you posted are both great.